# How to serialize XML to object from particular part of XML?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have problem how to serialize XML to list of objects but only from particular part of one, big XML. I mean something like that:

take data only from items and make list of item objects.

```
<tXML>
    <nameOfUser>MK</nameOfUser>
    <amouthOfPO>14</amouthOfPO>
    <todayDate></todayDate>
    <warehouses>
        <warehouse id="1">
            <name>AD1</name>
        </warehouse>
        <warehouse id="2">
            <name>AD2</name>
        </warehouse>
        <warehouse id="3">
            <name>AD3</name>
        </warehouse>
    </warehouses>
    <items>
        <warehause id="1">
            <items>
                <item>
                    <name>item1</name>
                    <protectionLevel>AMB</protectionLevel>
                    <description>DescAMB1FORID1</description>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <name>item2</name>
                    <protectionLevel>CHL</protectionLevel>
                    <description>DescCHL1FORID1</description>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <name>item3</name>
                    <protectionLevel>AMB</protectionLevel>
                    <description>3</description>
                </item>
            </items>
        </warehause>
        <warehause id="3">
            <items>
                <item>
                    <name>item1AMB2222</name>
                    <protectionLevel>AMBB222222</protectionLevel>
                    <description>DESCRIPTIONITEM1AM222222B</description>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <name>item222222CHL</name>
                    <protectionLevel>C222222222LL</protectionLevel>
                    <description>ITEM2CH22ILLERAD1</description>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <name>2222222222223</name>
                    <protectionLevel>222222223</protectionLevel>
                    <description>3222222222222</description>
                </item>
            </items>
        </warehause>
        <warehause id="3">
            <items>
                <item>
                    <name>item1333333AMB</name>
                    <protectionLevel>AM3333BB</protectionLevel>
                    <description>DESCR333IPTIONITEM1AMB</description>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <name>item233333CHL</name>
                    <protectionLevel>C33333HLL</protectionLevel>
                    <description>ITEM2CHI333LLERAD1</description>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <name>33</name>
                    <protectionLevel>33</protectionLevel>
                    <description>33</description>
                </item>
            </items>
        </warehause>
    </items>
</tXML>
```

My item class looks like below :

```
namespace UseFiles
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ProtectionLevel { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What is the best (optimally) way to change XML (only from ) for objects ? I thought about two ways:

1. xmlSerializer
2. or just to assign values in loop from XMLNodeList ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `best (optimally) way` can be interpreted as: 1 - best performance, 2 - more (easy) readable code.

The best performance I suppose shoul be working with `FileStream` using `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter`. But in your case this can cause some additional complications, because `items` located inside `wherehouses`, and any `item` should be inside particular 'wherehouse'. So you should find items insude concrete `wherehouse`, and after some updates save that items inside same `wherehouse`. Any items can be: 1 - updated, 2 - added, 3 - removed, from `wherehouse`, so updating of existing xml-document becomes much more complicated.

Based on the above, I recommend using `LinqToXml`, it not so performance efficient, but fast enought **in most cases**, have any tools you need (searching and replacing list of elements inside concrete xml-tag) and much more readable.

This is how you can use it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TestProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string _PATH = @"path to xml-file";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string myWherehouseId = "3";
            
            var document = XDocument.Load(_PATH);
            var itemsElement = document.Root.Element("items");

            List<Item> myItems = null;

            foreach (XElement wherehause in itemsElement.Elements())
            {
                if (wherehause.Attribute("id").Value == myWherehouseId)
                {
                    myItems = FromXml(wherehause.Element("items").Elements());

                    // Do some things
                    myItems[0].Name += "1";
                    myItems[0].Description += "2";
                    myItems.RemoveAt(1);
                    myItems.Add(
                        new Item
                        { 
                            Name = "Name212",
                            Description = "Sometext123213",
                            ProtectionLevel = "CHL"
                        });

                    XElement[] updatedElements = ToXml(myItems);

                    // replace old xml nodes with new ones
                    wherehause.Element("items").ReplaceNodes(updatedElements);
                    break;
                }
            }

            document.Save(_PATH);
        }

        public static List<Item> FromXml(IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
        {
            // you could use any custom mapper for conversion from XElement to Item
            return elements.Select(el => new Item
            {
                Name = el.Element("name").Value,
                ProtectionLevel = el.Element("protectionLevel").Value,
                Description = el.Element("description").Value                
            }).ToList();
        }

        public static XElement[] ToXml(List<Item> items)
        {
            // you could use any custom mapper for conversion from Item to XElement
            return items
                .Select(item => 
                    new XElement("item", 
                        new XElement("name", item.Name),
                        new XElement("protectionLevel", item.ProtectionLevel),
                        new XElement("description", item.Description)))
                .ToArray();
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ProtectionLevel { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my opinion `best (optimally) way` consists of a reasonable compromise between performance and code readability.

This is my best way ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your answer ! Could You also tell a little bit about deserialization? for example how to get only items from item bracket from this xml?

Comment: In few words: If you are using `XmlSerializer` some of `Deserialize` methods contains reader parameter, so you need to move that reader to tag, than you need to be deserialized, and call `Deserialize`. Deserialization should be not so hard, but serialization should be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, XmlReader way to go for parsing large xml files. Alternatively you can try [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.NETStandard) - an open source library to parse such large file with few lines of code.

```
using (var r = ChoXmlReader<Item>.LoadText(xml)
       .WithXPath("//item")
      )
{
    foreach (var rec in r)
        rec.Print();
}
```

Sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/otYq5j

Disclaimer: I'm author of this library.